# Cannot use Keyboard/Mouse?

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution, technical-issues

I can use the scroll wheel to select menu options, and I can click to fire, but it seems only my xbox 360 gamepad will allow me to aim or move. Which is terrible because I can't aim with my left thumb so I die, and that's not quite so bad but the loading times for this game are murder.

Pressing W,A,S,D move my character by about one millimeter, and they react like it does in regular windows, repeating after I hold the key for a second. But it's moving one millimeter per repeat so I'm basically stuck.

Also the mouse cursor is invisible in the menu but it moves and sometimes it appears for one frame (out of like 100).

In the controls menu the "Keyboard" option is disabled (it's red and I cannot select the option in the menu).

Has anybody else run into this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you disconnect the controller? Not really a "fix" but would definitely be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. Without the controller, I can't even exit the game, I have to do three-finger-salute and kill it from task manager because I cannot press the A button from the keyboard, even though I can choose the Exit Game option and press Enter to select it.

Comment: You're removing the controller before starting the game?

Comment: Yeah i'll go reinstall.

Comment: @Steven Make sure to report back and let us know if reinstalling resolved the issue. This is a fairly serious bug that I'm sure other have/will run into as well and would benefit from the info.

Comment: Some games I have (Batman: AA and Star Wars: TFU jump to mind) seem to start up in either "XBox 360" mode or "mouse/keyboard" mode and do not permit you to hop back and forth between the two.  It's a sloppy programming trend, it seems, and if reinstalling doesn't help I would look into the config files and see if you can find anything hard-coded for input; if not, try running the game with the 360 controller disconnected, like DMA suggested.

Comment: I was able to get it working on my other computer. I figure somewhere in between reinstalling it and reinstalling windows would get this problem fixed.

Comment: Did you try this: [Deus Ex: Human Revolution mouse lag?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/deus-ex-human-revolution-mouse-lag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - check the connection between PC and keybord/mouse. Just in case =)
Second - reinstall. And get the latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different mouse/keyboard or the connection. You can also try rebooting or updating your computer.